# Sentinel 1 creating ratio from polarizations

Tags: python, raster-calculator, numpy, sentinel-1

I am trying to perform a simple raster operation (In python) on two different bands (polarization VV and polarization VH) of the same SAR GRD product so that I have a co/cross-polarized ratio:

VV/VH

The original rasters are in Decibel range ~ (-25, 0) and the ratio contains some NaN as the result of division by zero.

The question is considering that the dynamic range of (ratio) intensities are now completely different from the original polarization bands ranges, what transformation should I apply to make the ratio image comparable to the 2 original bands (from the dynamic range point of view)?

I mean when you want to create a false RGB image out of 3 graybands you normally transform/normalize all three images into the range (0,255). Here I wonder if it is meaning full to do the same with the ratio image and bring it into the range of the first two images.

Comment: Which software are you working with?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to write in advance. I am using python/numpy for calculations.

Comment: As per the [Tour], there should only be One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question in response to requests for clarification.